# BIND9 sends notify to slave only with also-notify

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, rndc

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy for three days!
I'm replacing my Authoritative DNS servers with new ones and then I'm resetting all BIND9 configurations again to do a bit more "fine tuning" given the replacement.

I have configured a MASTER server and two SLAVE servers, I have configured a zone to be used as a test with a domain (FQDN) that I usually use for tests, the problem is this:

- When I update the zone and reboot / reload bind, from the logs I see that notifications are sent correctly but the all slaves, they do not receive (also verified with tcpdump port 53: no out from master)

`Feb 12 20:42:13 svr-3 named[12957]: zone test.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 20210                                                                                          21201)`

- If I add instead the directive "also-notify {slave_ip_1; slave_ip_2;}; notifications are sent and received correctly (verified with tcpdump port 53 and with bind logs) and obviously the transfer process starts and ends correctly

At this point, I believe that it is a problem on some configuration of the MASTER that I have escaped or set incorrectly, since the slaves receive correctly; it would appear as if it is not reading the authoritative NS records.

I am attaching the configuration files, perhaps with your help, I can find the error (the file is to be completed, I stopped as soon as I encountered this problem)

named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on { xxx; };
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        //IP da utilizzare per le richieste in uscita di aggiornamento zone e il forward dei dynamic updates
        transfer-source xxx;

        //Abilito le notifiche
        notify yes;

        //Quale IP utilizzare per le notifiche in uscita
        notify-source xxx;

        //IP da notificare in aggiunta degli NS RR
//      also-notify { yyy; zzz;  };

        auth-nxdomain no;

        // hide version number from clients for security reasons.
        version "Not Available";

        // disable recursion on authoritative DNS server.
        recursion no;

        // enable the query log
        querylog yes;

        // disallow zone transfer
        allow-transfer { none; };

};
```

zone file

```
; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
;
; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
;

$TTL    86400           ;TTL (1 Giorno)
$ORIGIN test.com.    ;Base Dominio

; Record Start of Authority (SOA)
@       IN      SOA     ns1.test.net. hostmaster.test.net. (
                       2021021201       ; Serial
                          21600         ; Refresh (6H)
                          10800         ; Retry (3H)
                         604800         ; Expire (1 Settimana)
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL (1 Settimana)
; Record A
@       10800   IN      A       123.345.678.123
www     10800   IN      A       123.345.678.123

; Record AAAA

; Record CNAME

; Record TXT

; Record SRV

; Record MX
@       3600    IN      MX      1       mail.test.net.
@       3600    IN      MX      10      mail2.test.net.

; Record NS
@       IN      NS      ns1.test.net.
@       IN      NS      ns2.test.net.
@       IN      NS      dns.otherdomain.it.
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "test.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/db.test.com";
      allow-query { any; };
      allow-transfer { key keytest; };
};
```

Comment: The obfuscated `NS` and `SOA` records (basis for the default NOTIFY behavior), makes it pretty much impossible to try to answer this.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the domain name with "test", it's ok?

Comment: and the slave config looks like.... and did you tcpdump TCP/53 or UDP (should be tcp for tsig) AND are you increasing the zone Serial number each time.

Comment: Every time I made modify or I want to update (for test) the zone file I increment the serial number... The slave work perfectly, because with "also-notify" enabled on master, the notify work... For tcpdump I haven't log to post, because without "also-notify" enabled, from the master no packet go out on port 53.

Comment: @MrTaik I still cannot make sense of it. This is one of these things where the devil quite likely is in the details and the details have been deliberately obfuscated away.

Comment: @Håkan Lindqvist Unfortunately, for the moment, (having the servers not protected properly) I prefer to obfuscate these details. I simply replaced the domain name with the word "test" and "otherdomain", the tld has remained the same, I don't understand what can change ;-)

Comment: @MrTaik I'm essentially just noting that with the provided information I cannot see a reason why you would get the claimed strange behavior. There are essentially the records mentioned before and the `notify-source` setting that you for whatever reason have explicitly set to something unknown (to us). And the described behavior is indeed strange, so it would appear that there probably is something in your environment that explains it. Problem is, with the lack of information sharing, you are probably the only who can realistically answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the point of putting into production the new machines for the management of the Authoritative DNS servers and at this point I was able to perform a more precise diagnosis.

The problem has been solved, I think it was due to the fact that in the transfer phase I registered the new GLUE records with the registrar, then I transferred all the zones to the new master server and at this point I reported the problem to you .

But I had not yet reported (with the registrar) the new DNS addresses, because obviously the machines were not yet complete with configurations; yesterday I proceeded to run a DNS UPDATE, then to make the new services functional and SURPRISE!

Now by disabling the "also-notify" function, the master server is able to send notifications to the slave machines.

I honestly did not think that bind was going to check which were the authoritative servers currently set up at the registrar, I thought that only the NS records set in the zone file were enough.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me with this problem, I hope this experience can be helpful.

Comment: Regarding `/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones`, if that file has reverse zones for rfc1918 networks and so on (my guess based on what is often included by distro packaging of BIND), it's completely redundant regardless as BIND has those built in without need for configuration. See https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#built-in-empty-zones

Comment: @Håkan Lindqvist Yes, but I understand that they are areas intended for non-internet traffic, as my servers are used only to respond to domain requests exclusively via the internet, technically they are not needed, right?

Comment: It's really whether it's an authoritative-only server (as you wrote initially) that matters, and agree in that regard you don't need these zones. My point was rather just that BIND actually has a pretty complete set of such zones built right into the software, which means that adding those zones to your configuration is actually pointless even if you have recursion enabled (as long as you just don't do some `disable-empty-zone` stuff that would disable the built in handling).